# Print onto same/separate line and replacing regex strings

Tags: regex, powershell

I am new to Powershell, and I have created a script to read a log file and output a file from only parts of the string on the same line to the file.

I am also new to regex also so this has been a relatively stiff curve so far!

Based on [this article](https://techtalk.gfi.com/windows-powershell-extracting-strings-using-regular-expressions/) I decided to craft a script on the same basis.

```
$input_path = 'C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\Desktop\Sample.log'
$output_file = 'C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\Desktop\Ouput.log'

if ($regex = '\b([1-9]|([012][0-9])|(3[01]))/([0]{0,1}[1/9]|1[012])/\d\d\d\d [012]{0,1}[0-9]:[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]\b|\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b|]\s(\w+)|\(\d*\)\D+\(2\)\D+\(2\)\w+|\(\d*\)\D+\([1-5]\)\w+') {select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file}
```

**Sample Log**

```
25/10/2018 16:48:23 PM 0710 PACKET  0000000028FB94C0 UDP  Rcv 69.160.33.71    8857  Q [0080       NOERROR] A      (16)offeringsmislead(3)com(0)
25/10/2018 16:48:23 AM 0714 PACKET  000000002CC599A0 UDP  Snd 8.8.8.8         3434  Q [1001   D   NOERROR] A      (10)controltag(3)net(0)
```

With the script I have mangled together I managed to write the following to a separate file:

**Current Output Log:** (this is on separate lines)

```
25/10/2018 16:48:23
69.160.33.71
] A
(16)offeringsmislead(3)com
25/10/2018 16:48:23
8.8.8.8
] A
(10)controltag(3)net
```

**I would like the desired output:**

```
25/10/2018 16:48:23 69.160.33.71 A offeringsmislead.com
25/10/2018 16:48:23 8.8.8.8 A controltag.net
```

I have tried to research how to print to new line, as well as replacing string from regex queries to get rid of/add the detail required.

Appreciate your responses.

Comment: Your Regular expression seems overly complex to me and there is to less sample data to give hints for a better one. You might benefit from using look arounds and named capture groups.

Comment: please post several REAL lines of the log file - and use CODE FORMATTING to preserve the layout. [*grin*] then post what you want those lines to look like in the new file - again, using code formatting so that multiple lines show as multiple lines. ///// if you can't figure out how to make things show clearly, you may want to link to a Gist.GitHub.com post of the text.

Comment: How do you decide what you are keeping? Why the A? is it the only character after the [...] that you need? How do you decide how to parse the URL on the last line? do you _only_ need the domain name? Can we assume that (3) is a period? Does your actual source file contain real date times? I would include that in your sample. What creates these logs? Can you intercept that data?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I have edited my original post. I hope that makes things a bit clearer.

Comment: @Matt thanks for your reply. The A denotes the dns record that is being queried. Either A, PTR, CNAME, MX would need to be extracted. You are correct, it is the string of text that is after the "]". I only need the domain name, yes. (3) I am assuming is the number of characters, but I would want it replacing with the period. I have updated the sample. I might be able to intercept the data.

Comment: thanks for the added info. it makes things a good deal more clear ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

Based on your new sample data this script with an enhanced RE using named capture groups:
**EDIT: changed the RegEx to get all domain levels.**

```
## Q:\Test\2018\10\27\SO_53047308.ps1
$input_path  = '.\Sample.log'
$output_file = '.\Output.log'

$RE = [regex]"^(?<dt>[0-9\/: ]{16,19}).*?(Rcv |Snd )(?<IP>(\d+\.){3}\d+)[^\]]+\] (?<RecType>[^ ]+) +(?<DOM>.*)$"

Get-Content $input_path | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_ -match $RE){
    "{0} {1} {2} {3}" -f $Matches.DT.Trim(),$Matches.IP,$Matches.RecType,$($Matches.Dom -replace '\(\d+\)','.').Trim('.')
  }
} | Set-Content $output_file
```

will output:

```
> gc .\Output.log
25/10/2018 16:48:23 69.160.33.71 A offeringsmislead.com
25/10/2018 16:48:23 8.8.8.8 A controltag.net
```

To better explain what the RE `+(?<DOM>.*)$` does:

- `+` matches all spaces following the record type
- `(?<DOM>.*)$` captures eveything `.*` upto the end of line `$` in the named capture group `DOM`
  `(16)offeringsmislead(3)com(0)`
  `(10)controltag(3)net(0)`
- `$($Matches.Dom -replace '\(\d+\)','.')` changes `(99)` to `.` at least one digit, as much as present.
  `.offeringsmislead.com.`
  `.controltag.net.`
- `.Trim('.')` strips leading/trailing dots
  `offeringsmislead.com`
  `controltag.net`

Comment: Thank you for your time with this. I have replaced the input and output paths and ran the query. The information that I see printed on the command line does not appear to be outputting to a file. What do I need to do to write the content onto a file? Many thanks.

Comment: Changed from `[PSCustomObject]` to direct text output to `$output_file`

Comment: That's great thank you. The output seems to be missing the TLD .co.uk, .com, .arpa etc can you inform me how to do this - and what the best method would be?

Comment: At the moment my RegEx matches just 2 domain levels, are by any chance the missing TLDs prepended by a 3rd level?

Comment: Changed the RE to get everything after the RecordType as DOM and replace all `(9)` with a dot trimmimg the leading/trailing ones..

Comment: Thanks @LotPings. Will try to understand how this works a little better now.

Comment: Hi @LotPings - I have a file that has a list for whitelisted domain names such as controltag.net. 
Would it be difficult to (A) scan that file after identifying the $RE matches and (B) discarding domain names that are matched using $RE, and then (C) writing the matches "25/10/2018 16:48:23 69.160.33.71 A offeringsmislead.com" to a separate file based on No match being found? I am trying to get a list of queries that do not match the queries on the whitelist. Hope that makes sense, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

i would likely prefer to use string operations, but regex *is* usually faster. [*grin*]

presuming `$InStuff` contains the two lines you posted, this will grab the parts you seem to want ...

```
$Instuff[0] -match '^(?<TimeStamp>.+?) [AM|PM].+[Rcv|Snd] (?<IP>.+?)\s{2,}.+] (?<RecordType>.+?)\s{2,}\(\d+\)(?<Domain>.+?)\(\d{1,}\)(?<TLD>.+?)\(\d{1,}\)$'
```

then the automatic var `$Matches` will have the various named matches ready to be used. here's the output for the 1st line you posted ...

```
Name                           Value                                                                              
----                           -----
Domain                         offeringsmislead
TLD                            com
IP                             69.160.33.71
TimeStamp                      25/10/2018 16:48:23
RecordType                     A
0                              25/10/2018 16:48:23 PM 0710 [*...snip...*]
```

you can address those matches via `$Matches.Domain` or any of the other property names.

---

since it was requested, here is a full version of the code with "save to file" ... [*grin*]

```
# fake reading in a file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
25/10/2018 16:48:23 PM 0710 PACKET  0000000028FB94C0 UDP  Rcv 69.160.33.71    8857  Q [0080       NOERROR] A      (16)offeringsmislead(3)com(0)
25/10/2018 16:48:23 AM 0714 PACKET  000000002CC599A0 UDP  Snd 8.8.8.8         3434  Q [1001   D   NOERROR] A      (10)controltag(3)net(0)
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

$NamedRegex = '^(?<TimeStamp>.+?) [AM|PM].+[Rcv|Snd] (?<IP>.+?)\s{2,}.+] (?<RecordType>.+?)\s{2,}\(\d+\)(?<Domain>.+?)\(\d{1,}\)(?<TLD>.+?)\(\d{1,}\)$'
$CleanedFileName = "$env:TEMP\CleanedVersion.log"

$Results = foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    # supress unwanted False/True output
    $Null = $IS_Item -match $NamedRegex
    # join the named matches with a single space
    #    plus, join the Domain & TLD with a dot
    #    if you want things padded to a constant colum width, use `.PadLeft()`
    $Matches.TimeStamp, $Matches.IP, $Matches.RecordType, ($Matches.Domain, $Matches.TLD -join '.') -join ' '
    }

# on screen output
$Results

# send to text file
$Results |
    Set-Content -LiteralPath $CleanedFileName
```

onscreen output ...

```
25/10/2018 16:48:23 69.160.33.71 A offeringsmislead.com
25/10/2018 16:48:23 8.8.8.8 A controltag.net
```

"cleanedversion.log" content ...

```
25/10/2018 16:48:23 69.160.33.71 A offeringsmislead.com
25/10/2018 16:48:23 8.8.8.8 A controltag.net
```

Comment: Thanks for this Lee, I would need each part printed on the same line. Is this difficult to do? Also I was not entirely sure what else was needed to run this query.

Comment: @ChicoRipa - take a look at my answer. it now includes the full script instead of just the parsing part. [*grin*]

Comment: Thank you @Lee_Dailey [grinsback]

Comment: @ChicoRipa - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a tad ... [*grin*]

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried to modify the query to include Get-Content with no luck. Hopefully I will learn how/where I went wrong in future, but this is still a hill to climb/get my head around.

Comment: @ChicoRipa - you otta be able to replace the 4 lines starting at `$InStuff = @'` with `$InStuff = Get-Content -LiteralPath $FullFileName` and run the remaining code as-is.